# Immutable Update React Hooks Array Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, immutability

I succesfully change the menu state, with hooks but...

```
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState([
    {
      parent: 'User',
      permission: false,
      children:[
        {name: 'Vendor', permission: false, readonly: true},
        {name: 'Client', permission: false, readonly: true},
        {name: 'User', permission: false, readonly: true},
      ]
    }
  ]);

  const toggleParent = (key) => {
    let data = {...menu};
    data[key].permission = !data[key].permission
    setMenu(data);
  };
```

end up getting error in mapping function, it says:

> menu.map is not a function

here is the mapping function:

```
                  {menu.map((value, key) => (
                    <Switch
                      checked={value.permission}
                      onChange={() => toggleParent(key)}
                      color="primary"
                      name="checkedB"
                      inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'primary checkbox' }}
                    />
                  ))}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is coming from `{...menu}`. Usually this error happens when you call `.map()` not on an array. You need to have an `[]` instead.

Try the following:

```
const toggleParent = (key) => {
    let data = [...menu];
    data[key].permission = !data[key].permission;
    setMenu(data);
};
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your code, Your menu is an array and your are assigning it an object and using a map over it.

**Here is the correct way of doing this.**

```
const toggleParent = (key) => {
    let data = [...menu];
    data[key].permission = !data[key].permission
    setMenu(data);
  };
```